# Real Purpose of Static Inner Classes

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

I am a newbie in Java. While learning I have come across inner classes- static and non-static inner classes. Though I have understood how they function, yet I am unable to figure out their real purpose!

I request the community to clear this doubt in a way even a kid would understand. I have browsed through multiple sites, yet their explanation didn't satiate my query.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to define a `class` inside a class (`nested`)
and you also want to **declare objects of that class from other classes**,
then you need a `static nested class`. 
If you **don't want** to create an object of this nested class outside of the parent class, then `static` is **not needed**.

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes can have the properties of the outer class. Consider the following example:

```
class School {
 // school has classroom
// school has a canteen


class Student {
// students can have the access of classroom & canteen
// Students can have their own properties like books, bags
}


 class Teachers {
// Teachers can have the access of classroom & canteen
// Teachers can have their own properties like board, staffroom
} 

 }
```

Inner classes really only exist to help the developer organize code; the compiler treats inner classes just like any other class, except that the inner classes have a limited scope, and are therefore tethered to the class they are defined with. Also, inner classes can have properties of outer classes.

For detailed information please refer the following link to get more idea:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learn-java-for-android-development-inner-classes--mobile-3530

Comment: Can you share scenarios where static and non-static inner classes would be useful?